# java put HashMap elements inside foreach loop use only the last one

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a strength problem about adding elements into an `HashMap` inside a loop. I make sure to declare map before iteration, to ignore it's recreation each time but I got the same problem - in map remains only the last element from my loop iteration. The code is

```
//declare map         
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

//my loop iteration
String[] array = {"element1", "element2", "element3"};
for (String str: array) {
map.put("uniqueKey", str);
}
```

as a result, for simplicity calling `map.toString()`,  I get only `{uniqueKey=element3}`

I just don't understand why this happens, any explanations will be appreciated.

Comment: `"uniqueKey"` isn't unique for each key: it's the same hardcoded value.

Comment: because you only have one key, and overwrite the value for that key over and over until your loop is over and your map only contains the last element of the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you're trying to ignore the general concept of `Map`s about unique keys. Make your `"uniqueKey"` "really" unique as you repeat it in the loop :)

I'll give you an example to understand:

```
 Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
 map.put("1", str1);
 map.put("2", str2);
 map.put("3", str3);
 map.put("1", str4); // value str1 is overwritten by str4
```

Think of `Map`s as `List`s, but with indices other than primitive `int`s and without the need to have the indices in range `0`..`size-1`